# Map as a function parameter in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Error: `Non-nullable instance field id must be initialised.`

Source: `Picture.fromMap`

```
import 'dart:typed_data'; // Uint8List

class Picture {
 int id;
 String title;
 Uint8List? picture;

 Picture({this.id = 0, this.title = "", this.picture });

 Picture.fromMap(Map map) {
   id = map[id];
   title = map[title];
   picture = map[picture];
 }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
   "id": id,
   "title": title,
   "picture" : picture,
 };
}
```

What is the way to initialise `Map` when being passed to a function parameter, or how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keyword `late` when you know that it will be initialized later. otherwise use  `int id=0;` and similar for other non nullable fields as a default initialization

```
class Picture {
 late int id;
 late String title;
 Uint8List? picture;

 Picture({this.id = 0, this.title = "", this.picture });

 Picture.fromMap(Map map) {
   id = map[id];
   title = map[title];
   picture = map[picture];
 }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
   "id": id,
   "title": title,
   "picture" : picture,
 };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you init at the `Picture.fromMap` constructor **function** body. Try the below code.

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data'; // Uint8List

class Picture {
  int id;
  String title;
  Uint8List? picture;

  Picture({this.id = 0, this.title = "", this.picture});

  factory Picture.fromMap(Map map) {
    return Picture(
      id: map["id"],
      title: map["title"],
      picture: map["picture"],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "picture": picture,
      };
}
```

OR

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data'; // Uint8List

class Picture {
  int id;
  String title;
  Uint8List? picture;

  Picture({this.id = 0, this.title = "", this.picture});

  Picture.fromMap(Map map)
      : id = map["id"],
        title = map["title"],
        picture = map["picture"];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "picture": picture,
      };
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this should help and what are we doing here.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl I think the `late` keyword has risks if you forgotton initializing fields. So I recomand using the `factory` constructor or the initialier list.

Comment: I am new to flutter. It would be helpful if you could explain your statements in your answer.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl,  I added the explanation as an answer below. You should get familiar with constructors in Dart.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options for such instance field assignments.

1. Named Generative Constructor
2. Named Factory Constructor

**Generative Constructor:**
You can use initializer lists following a (:) colon

**Factory Constructor:**
You can use any business logic and initialize your instance fields (variables) in the body of the constructor, just like regular functions.

Exapmle:

```
class User {
  String name;
  int id;

   **// Named generative constructor**
   User.fromJson(Map<String,Object> json)
     : name = json['name'] as String,
       id = json['id'] as int;

   **// Factory constructor**
  factory User.fromJson(Map<String,Object> json) {
    final id = json['id'] as int;
    final name = json['name'] as String;
    return User(id:id, name:name);
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code block, you didn't define variable nullable. You have to define all variables with null safety.

```
int? id;
String? title;
Uint8List? picture;
```

Comment: Not exactly. These (id, title) instance variables are not necessarily to be nullable.